# Google Analytics Number are way Higher Than my own script

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have coded a script to collect the page views and also "Click" and "Scroll" events data. However there are 2 issues:

Google Analytics shows 520K Users while My Site's total page views are 480K .

Second,

My script shows Google.com as top referrer while GA is showing "Social". More than half of the referrers are blank using my script.

I want to use my own script to target the users in first party world.

Problem may be with the script but Im not sure why there is such a big gap.

Here are the numbers from Google Analytics for 5 days

[image: Numbers from Google Analytics]

And these are the Page Views from My own script are :

[image: My Pageviews]

The code which Im using to include the script is :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://my-server-url.com/tracker.js?key=2hj34hj324h242k3hj42"></script>
```

This is the code in the above file

function sendData(){

```
    try{
        
        logg('onload called at : '+ new Date().getTime());
        var  dt = new Date();
        var defaultJson = {};
        

            var  dt = new Date();
            defaultJson =  {
            'type': 'pageview',
            'timeinmillis': dt.getTime(),
            'date':dt.toString()
            }

        defaultJson['url'] = window.location.href;
        defaultJson['originalReferrer'] =document.referrer;
        defaultJson['timezone'] =dt.getTimezoneOffset().toString();
        defaultJson['screenHeight'] =window.screen.height;
        defaultJson['screenWidth'] =window.screen.width;
        try{

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = 'https://my-server-url.com/data_handler?key=2hj34hj324h242k3hj42';
        xhr.open("POST", url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                console.log('Sent');
            }
        };
                
        xhr.send(data);
                
        }catch(err)){
                
}
        
sendData()
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example] also include screenshots of the data you are comparing it with.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have added that.

Comment: You need to remember this is a multi dimensional database not a relational database.    Your code isn't requesting all of the dimensions and metrics in your image.   You won't get the same results if the request isn't the same.

Comment: I am not too much concerned about what I am capturing and what Google analytics is capturing. I am more concerned in the numbers. Those should match. My real question is that is my script executing and if not then why

Comment: Well fix your code so that you request default channel group, users,newusers,sessions,,bouncerate,page/sessions,avg session duration,goal1,goal1,goal1  and then you should get back the same results.

Comment: I get your point. However this could have been a valid answer had my numbers been more than Google Analytics. Here im not looking to narrow down my results

Comment: Then your numbers will not match what you are seeing in the report.   If you want the numbers to match you must make a request that is exactly the same.